# Creating a custom column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a custom column which is the multiplication of 2 existing columns.

```
(
  select
    omdDeliveryQty * omlUnitPriceBase AS 'Value'
) *
from
  SalesOrderDeliveries
  Left Outer Join SALESORDERLINES On OMDSALESORDERID = OMLSALESORDERID
  And OMDSALESORDERLINEID = OMLSALESORDERLINEID
```

Comment: Why do you have your select clause in brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
select
  *,
  d.omdDeliveryQty * l.omlUnitPriceBase AS 'Value'
from SalesOrderDeliveries d
left outer join SALESORDERLINES l
  on d.OMDSALESORDERID = l.OMLSALESORDERID 
 and d.OMDSALESORDERLINEID = l.OMLSALESORDERLINEID
```

Don't forget to add aliases to each table (I added `d` and `l`) to make the query eaier to read and to debug.